# A fantastic movie about the arrival of a native of a planet of children

Tags: story-identification, movie

About 7-8 years ago, I watched a movie about a little girl who came to Earth from a planet where humans never get older, always stay as a kid. She was over 200 years old, but appeared as a child. She had a great store of knowledge and spoke with people on Earth about her planet, and was unable to understand why they divided time into seconds, minutes, and hours. The longevity of their race may have had to do with keeping their soul young.

Comment: How long ago is "years ago"? Any idea how old the movie is? Did you watch it on TV or in a theatre? Was it meant for kids or adults? Genre? Live action or animated? Any other details would be great.

Comment: Also, "never get older, always stay as a kid."- does that mean they never physically looks like an adult but they still die, or they stop growing at a certain age and are immortal?

Comment: like 7-8 years ago,i wacthed it on the tv.It wasnt an animation movie.She was like over 200 old years with earth time,but she was just a kid with lots of knowledge.She was telling human beings about her planet.And she was asking them why they are dividing time into the second minutes and hours

Comment: After being a kid,they never get older.Looks like a kid yet their knowledeg is increasing like adults but they protect their soul ,their soul always  stay like kids

Comment: Was it in English? Where were you when you watched it? Did it have any particular style of animation, such as Japanese anime?

Comment: it is not ANİMATİON MOVİE!!

Comment: SOMEONE MADE A MİSTAKE WHİLE CORRECTİNG MY GRAMMAR MİSTAKES!!!

Comment: No need to get so worked up over it. :) You can edit your own posts too.

Comment: I did indeed err.